# Diferença entre MOV e MOV ptr

Tags: c, assembly

Se calhar não é o sítio ideal para perguntar isto, mas vou ter teste e não percebo a diferença entre MOV e MOV ptr.
por exemplo, se tivermos em linguagem c "unsigned char x,y", em assembly se quisermos "X=2" usamos
`MOV x,2`

mas se tivermos "unsigned char tabbyte[4]" e quisermos "tabbyte[0]=15" já se usa
`MOV byte ptr tabbyte [0],15`.

Alguém me consegue explicar a diferença, e quando é que devemos usar simplesmente o MOV e quando devemos usar o MOV ptr?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que parece você já viu isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916891/difference-between-mov-and-mov-ptr).

A explicação é a que está lá no link.

Numa instrução do tipo

```
 mov [ESI], al ; Store a byte-size value
```

o assembler (masm, tasm, etc) sabe qual instrução de máquina usar, porque a origem é o registrador AL que tem 8 bits (1 byte).

Numa instrução do tipo

```
mov [ESI], 5   ; Error: operand must have the size specified
```

o assembler não sabe qual instrução de máquina usar, porque "5" pode ser um byte com o valor 5, ou uma word com o valor 5, etc.

Então é preciso dar mais informações ao assembler para ele poder gerar a instrução de máquina certa:

```
; move o valor 0x05 (8 bits) para o byte cujo endereço está em ESI
mov  BYTE PTR [ESI], 5

; move o valor 0x0005 (16 bits) para a word cujo endereço está em ESI
mov  WORD PTR [ESI], 5

; move o valor 0x00000005 (32 bits) para a double-word cujo endereço está em ESI
mov  DWORD PTR [ESI], 5
```

Note que apesar da instrução assembly ser a mesma nestes 3 casos (MOV) na verdade o código de máquina é diferente, por isso o programa assembler (masm, tasm, etc) precisa dessa informação adicional: byte ptr, word ptr, dword ptr.

PS. em minha resposta anterior sobre esse assunto eu não me preocupei muito com isso, por garantia eu usei byte ptr, word ptr, talvez mesmo em lugares em que não era estritamente necessário.